# Renaming/Mapping Cygwin Folders

Tags: cygwin

Can I safely rename the cygdrive folder? Also, I would like to add other folders at root and map them to folders on windows in the same way as /cygdrive/c maps to my C drive. Is that possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can.  See [The Cygwin Mount Table](http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#mount-table) in Cygwin's documentation.  I have my documents folder mounted as /doc.  These mounts end up in the registry and are retained across reboots etc.

Comment: Some files under `/etc` in Cygwin are mounted as links to `/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/drivers/etc`. These links will get broken if cygdrive disappears.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't rename cygdrive as I don't know what that would do, but you can map other directories at root to various windows directories using the `mount` command.